# Flying press damage calculation in Pokemon XY

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I suppose I got this question because I'm not too familiar with how Flying Press works, so say I use it against a pokemon that's weak against both Flying and Fighting (whatever combination it may be, and it may not even exist). Would this apply BOTH super effective? So would it be a 4x + 1.5x from fighting STAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damage effectiveness is multiplicative, you can tell by how an attack interacts with dual-typed Pokemon.

So, to calculate the effectiveness multiplier for Flying Press, you first find the multiplier for the Fighting-type and then multiply it by the multiplier for Flying-type, or vice-versa. So, let's take using Flying Press against a Fighting/Flying Pokemon like you suggested.

First, we find the Fighting-type effectiveness. Against a Fighting/Flying-type, Fighting's offensive effectiveness is... not very effective or a 0.5x multiplier. Now, we find Flying-type effectiveness, which is 2x against a Fighting/Flying type. Finally, we multiply these two multipliers to find the final effectiveness multiplier. `2 * 0.5 = 1`, so we end up with a final effectiveness multiplier of 1, which is a neutral hit.

Now, let's try to find the effectiveness against a Pokemon that is both weak to Fighting and Flying. Pangoro is Dark/Fighting. We first calculate the Flying-type bonus, which is 2x. Then, we find the Fighting-type bonus, which is also 2x. We then combine the two multipliers, which gets us `2 * 2 = 4`. Flying Press would do 4x damage against Pangoro.

Comment: Too bad there's no type that's weak to both fighting and flying. I'd love to land an 8x damage attack.

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you know a move/type combination where an 8x attack is possible?

Comment: @eggy Unfortunately, it isn't possible as an 8x attack bonus requires a multiplier stack of `4 * 2`, which means at least one type needs to be weak to both Fighting and Flying. And as of now, no one type is weak to both Fighting and Flying.

Comment: @eggy not for Flying Press, but if there existed a dual Grass/Water type move, it would in fact be 16x effective against a Rock/Ground Pokemon.

Comment: @Yuki another way to look at Flying Press is that it has its own type chart, and treat it like its own type. Flying Press is super-effective against Normal, Grass, Ice, Fighting and Dark; not very effective against Electric, Poison, Flying, Psychic and Fairy; and has no effect on Ghost. There's a graphical representation here: http://pokemondb.net/move/flying-press

Comment: @eggy et al- If you use [Forest's Curse](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Forest%27s_Curse_%28move%29) on a Scizor, it will gain the Grass typing, making it Bug, Steel & Grass, which would be x8 weak to Fire